# Losing the value of this keyword when using it with instance level variables in a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two classes one of them is the *parent class* and the other one is the *child class* and what I'm trying to achieve is to access the values of *child classe's* instance level variables by using `this` keyword in a field that is declared in the *parent class*. But when I try to do so it returns `undefined`. Can anyone please explain what might be going wrong here. Below I've pasted a code snippet for your reference. Thanks!

```js
class Parent {
  someField = {
     someValue: 'Values are ::: '+ this.value1 + ' ' + this.value2,
     childType2: "Some gibberish"
   }

  initialize(childType1) {
     this.someField = this.someField[childType1];
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   value1 = "someValue 1"
   value2 = "someValue 2"
} 

const child = new Child();
child.initialize("someValue");
console.log(child.someField);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that `this` is wrong, it's a matter of timing. Your code initializing `someField` runs as part of the `Parent` constructor, **before** your code initializing `value1` and `value2` runs (as part of the `Child` constructor). So you get `undefined` when reading them.

The way public fields work in JavaScript, the definition of the property defined by the field declaration becomes part of the constructor's code, exactly as though you had written it at the beginning of the constructor (just after any call to `super`) (but [effective] using `Object.defineProperty`, not just simple assignment; [details](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#major-design-points)). That is, your code is the effectively the same as this:

```js
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "someField", {
            value: {
                someValue: 'Values are ::: '+ this.value1 + ' ' + this.value2,
                childType2: "Some gibberish"
            },
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }

    initialize(childType1) {
        this.someField = this.someField[childType1];
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
        Object.defineProperty(this, "value1", {
            value: "someValue 1",
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
        Object.defineProperty(this, "value2", {
            value: "someValue 2",
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
} 

const child = new Child();
child.initialize("someValue");
console.log(child.someField);
```

Comment: *(Sorry, copy-and-paste error, if you see `someField = {` in `Parent` in the code snippet above, hit refresh. Forgot to delete it.)*

Comment: Great answer, thanks! that's makes it clear, but this arises one more question in my mind, since we're calling `super()` without any preceding object. then how does the value of `this` gets bound to the call of `super`?

Comment: @ansme - It doesn't. :-) `this` remains `undefined` until the base constructor is reached (in this case, `Parent`), then just prior to the code in `Parent` running, the JavaScript engine creates the object and binds it to `this`. In `Child`, if you tried to use `this` prior to calling `super` you'd get a ReferenceError for the same reason you do using a `let` variable before the `let` statement.

Comment: @ansme - For what it's worth, I cover this stuff in detail in Chapter 4 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, sure! I'll check it out. :)